# Suspend not working

Tags: suspend, macbook

Suspend does not go suspend/sleep, it wakes immediately, around 2 secs after the suspend.

system:
elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
Macbook Air 13" Mid 2013

Comment: https://github.com/elementary/feedback/issues/40